# Update table with random numbers in kdb+q

Tags: database, kdb

when I run the following script:

```
tbl: update prob: 1?100 from tbl;
```

I was expecting that I get a new column created with each row having a random number. However, I get back a column containing the same number for all the rows in the table.

How do I resolve this? I need to update my existing table and not create a table from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using 1?100 you are only requesting 1 random value within the range of 0-100. If you use 10?100, you will be returned a list of 10 random values between 0-100.

So to do this in an update you want to use something like this

```
tbl:([]time:5?.z.p;sym:5?`3;price:5?10f;qty:5?10)

time                          sym price     qty
-----------------------------------------------
2012.02.19D18:34:27.148501760 gkn 8.376952  9
2008.07.29D20:23:13.601434560 odo 7.041609  3
2007.02.07D08:17:59.482332864 pbl 0.955069  9
2001.04.27D03:36:44.475531384 aph 1.127308  2
2010.03.03D03:35:55.253069888 mgi 0.7663449 6

update r:abs count[i]?0h from tbl

time                          sym price     qty r
-----------------------------------------------------
2012.02.19D18:34:27.148501760 gkn 8.376952  9   23885
2008.07.29D20:23:13.601434560 odo 7.041609  3   19312
2007.02.07D08:17:59.482332864 pbl 0.955069  9   10372
2001.04.27D03:36:44.475531384 aph 1.127308  2   25281
2010.03.03D03:35:55.253069888 mgi 0.7663449 6   27503
```

Note that I am using type short and abs to return positive values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to seed your initial data, using something like rand(time), otherwise it will use the same seed, and thus, give the same sequence of random numbers.

EDIT:  Per https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/SystemCommands

Use \S?n, where n is any integer.

EDIT2:  Check out https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/SystemCommands#.5CS_.5Bn.5D_-_random_seed for how to use random numbers, please.

Comment: As in, what I get is a column with the number 34 throughout. So seeding is not what I am looking.

Comment: It sounds like you are using \S to get the random number, which is resetting the random number seed.  Use something like 5?10, which generates the next five "random" numbers in the sequence less than 10.  Do not create them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Just generate as many random numbers as you have rows using `count tbl`:

First create your table `tbl`:

```
tbl:([]date:reverse .z.d-til 100;price:sums 100?1f)

  date       price    
--------------------
2018.04.26 0.2426471
2018.04.27 0.6163571
2018.04.28 1.179559 
..
```

Then add a column of random numbers between 0 and 100:

```
update rdn:(count tbl)?100 from tbl

date       price     rdn
------------------------
2018.04.26 0.2426471 25 
2018.04.27 0.6163571 33 
2018.04.28 1.179559  13 
..
```

[image: histogram of the generated random numbers between 0 and 100]